# Azure Container Apps with internal VNET faills to provision

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-apps

I want to create a Azure Container Apps Environment that uses an already existing Subnet with /23 addresses. The Environment gets created but after a couple of hours without any response I get this on the Overview page of the Environment: The Container Apps Environment failed to provision. In the  Activity Log there is only the create Activity and this succeeded. Trying the same with Terraform azApi managedEnvironment gives the same error. I am honestly at a loss right now I can not find anything in the Internet and I do not have dedicated Microsoft support at hand.

I tried a lot of different things:

- redeploying the Subnet that the Environment should be connected to
- tried a different subnet (also did not work) in the same VNET
- tried to provision it via CLI and terraform both did not work
- tried to find clear error messages in Log Analytics as well as the Activity Log, both are giving me a succeded deployment as feedback..
- the subnet is NOT delegated to any service (as Microsoft Documentation says that it will fail to provision if it is delegated)

A hind to where I could find clearer Error codes/messages would also be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Consumption only environment it doesn´t support User Defined Routes, make sure there isn´t a route table associated to the subnet.

Another important point to keep in mind is that the subnet must be dedicated to the Container Apps, it cannot be shared with any other resource.

You should also try to use a subnet with a /21 address range, although the documentation says the minimum size is /23. I currently have a container app environment running in a subnet with this size and I had no problem in the deployment. I would also recommend to try to deploy it in a different region to make sure it´s not something wrong in the backend for the specific region you are using.